# Why is my TabControl ignoring my ItemsPanelTemplate?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, itemspanel, itemspaneltemplate

I've used the `ItemsPanelTemplate` on other controls such as the `ListBox`, so I figured doing the same thing for the `TabControl` would be simple.

Apparently, I'm missing something and the `TabControl` is completely ignoring what I place in the `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

I have xaml that looks kinda of like this:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Right" ItemsSource="{Binding Components}">
     <TabControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapPanel />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </TabControl.ItemsPanel>
</TabControl>
```

I've tried replacing `WrapPanel` with `UniformGrid` to see if there was a difference and it behaves the same.  I do have a `ControlTemplate` for `TabItem`, but I tried removing it and it made no difference so I don't think that's effecting my problem.

Comment: It's kind of weird to replace the ItemsPanel from a TabPanel to a WrapPanel... it makes no sense to do that.

Comment: well it's not my end goal to use a wrappanel there. i tried it and was mostly wondering why it didn't work like I thought it would.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking to overwrite the `Template`, not the `ItemsPanel`

You can overwrite `TabControl.ItemTemplate` (or `TabItem.Template`) to alter the appearance of the Tabs along the top, `TabControl.ContentTemplate` to alter the template used for the content of the Tab, or `TabControl.Template` to alter the overall template of the TabControl.

I wasn't even aware that TabControl's had an ItemsPanel. I've only ever used that with an ItemsControl, where the ItemsPanel affects what kind of control contains the items in the collection. If the TabControl has that property, I expect it's only because it inherited it from some base class

Comment: well I'm actually already using TabControl.ItemTemplate to alter the appearance of the tabs (I just posted a super simple piece of xaml), but what I really want to do is enclose all the tabs into a scrollviewer, because I have cases where there's too many tabs to display and they're running off the screen.

Comment: @townsean I overwrite the `TabControl.Template` to do that. Use `IsItemsHost="True"` wherever you want your top Tabs to be (eg `<StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />`), and `<ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" />` for wherever you want the currently selected Tab Content to go

Comment: @Rachel: Correct, TabControl inherits from ItemsControl, which contains an ItemsPanel property. The TabControl sets this as a type of TabPanel. The user attempting to change it to a WrapPanel breaks the TabControl because the control was not designed to work with the WrapPanel, but instead a TabPanel (or a class that derives from it).

Comment: when i set ContentSource="SelectedContent", i get the msg: "Cannot bind properties of ContentPresenter because there is no property named 'SelectedContent' on type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control'." I'm placing the ContentPresenter inside of a StackPanel, which is inside of the ControlTemplate for the TabControl. ControlTemplates are my Achilles Heel @_@

Comment: @townsean Make sure your ControlTemplate has the TargetType defined, or it will default to a generic control template. `<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" ... >`

Comment: Hi Rachel, but what if i wanted to support any Panel without the need to re-define the template each time. I tried to use a ContentPresenter to show ItemsPanel, but i couldn't make it work. It seems much harder than it should be.

Comment: Adding some info some years later:
The TabControls xaml is a little strange in that it has a hard coded TabPanel instead of an ItemsPresenter. If you use an ItemsPresenter instead, the ItemsPanelTemplate is used, and the TabControl works just fine if you use a StackPanel for instance. 
You just loose the benefits of the TabPanel like MultiRow or bringing the selected item to the front.
I would have expected the TabControl to use an ItemsPresenter like an ItemsControl is supposed to, and use a default ItemsPanelTemplate that uses the TabPanel.